# Expression and Assign, variables

Tags: c#, expression, assign

I wondered how to change the value of a variable using Expression.Assign

And i made it:

```
            object valueToSet = "test value";
            object obj = string.Empty;
            Func<object, object> variabl = x => obj = x;
            Expression<Func<object, object>> expr = s => variabl(s);
            ParameterExpression newValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");

            var repExp = ReplaceParameter(expr, newValue, expr.Parameters[0].Name);

            var test = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(((Expression<Func<object, object>>)repExp).Body, false, newValue);
            test.Compile().Invoke(valueToSet);
```

Help Code

```
public static Expression ReplaceParameter(Expression expression,
            ParameterExpression parameter, string name)
    {
        return new ExpressionParameterReplacer(parameter, name).Visit(expression);
    }

    internal class ExpressionParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression _parameter;
        private readonly string _name;

        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Name == _name && (node.Type == _parameter.Type ||
                node.Type.IsAssignableFrom(_parameter.Type)))
            {
                return base.VisitParameter(_parameter);
            }

            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }

        internal ExpressionParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter, string name)
        {
            _parameter = parameter;
            _name = name;
        }
    }
```

But after I try to generate these results under the method, everything immediately breaks

```
            object valueToSet = "test value";
            object obj = string.Empty;
            var expr = BuildVariableSetter(obj);
            ParameterExpression newValue = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "value");
            var repExp = ReplaceParameter(expr, newValue, expr.Parameters[0].Name);

            var test = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(((Expression<Func<object, object>>)repExp).Body, false, newValue);
            test.Compile().Invoke(valueToSet);
```

wrapper method

```
public static Expression<Func<object, object>> BuildVariableSetter(object variable)
    {
        Func<object, object> objFunc = x => variable = x;
        Expression<Func<object, object>> variableExp = s => objFunc(s);
        return variableExp;
    }
```

I know that the compiler creates an instance of an object for the expression tree, thereby essentially calling its mirror copy, but this is not explicitly expressed here.

Any solution?

Comment: _"everything immediately breaks"_ into what? Exceptions?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen the direction in which the code was written. nothing happening, after invoke Action.